# IF depending on number of files per folder --unix

Tags: file, unix, if-statement, count, ls

I want to do different actions based on the number of files in each folder which start with same two letters --- if files in TS are less than or equal 6 to do one set of actions and otherwise do another set
my data looks like this

```
files/TS01 -- which has 2 files  
files/TS02 -- which has 5 files 
files/TS03 -- which has 2 files 
files/TS04 -- which has 7 files
files/TS05 -- which has 9 files
```

I have tried

```
FILES="$TS*"
for W in $FILES
do
    doc=$(basename $W) 
    if [ $W -le 6 ] 
    then
    ....
    done ...
    fi
done
```

but I get an error saying "integer expression expected"

I have tried to

```
if [ ls $W -le 6 ]
```

I get another erros saying "too many arguments"

Can you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of lines I would recomend piping ls -l into wc -l, this will spit out the number of lines in your directory as follows...

```
Atlas $ ls -l | wc -l
    19
```

I've made a small script which shows how you could then use this result to conditionally do one thing or another...

```
#!/bin/bash

amount=$(ls -l | wc -l)

if [ $amount -le 5 ]; then
    echo -n "There aren't that many files, only "
else
    echo -n "There are a lot of files, "
fi

echo $amount
```

When executed on a folder with 19 files it echoes..

```
Atlas $ ./howManyFiles.sh
    There are a lot of files, 19
```

and on one with less then 5 files...

```
Atlas $ ./howManyFiles.sh
    There aren't that many files, only 3
```

Hopefully this helps show you how to get a useable file count from a folder, and then how to use those results in an "if" statement!

Comment: I am not managing to get the result you present, I am editing to question to show the data structure

Comment: what happens when you run `ls -l | wc -l` on the directories?

Comment: I am running this inside sub-directory, when I run that i gives me the number of files in the main directory and it does not go through the loop --- I solved the problem with `amount=$(ls $W | wc -l )` -- thanx for the help

Comment: Ahh, okay so you are not in the directory you need the file count of.  In that case, you'll want to run `ls -l myDir | wc -l`